# How to find the list of files added freshly to a cvs directory

Tags: cvs

How to find the list of files added freshly to a cvs directory

Answer (score 2):

Using the cvs history command you can get a lot of information, you can also limit the information you get if you know all the little arguments.

```
cvs history -a -x A
```

Will get you all the history for added files (-a for all users, -x A gives you information on only added files), you can limit that more if you add the -w flag for the local directory.  It's hard to get the "freshly" requirement  done, since there is no specific option for that.  If you have the module tagged it's much easer to find the history back to the tag, just use the -t TAGNAME argument and you'll have all added files since that tag:

```
cvs history -a -x A -t TAGNAME
```

or you could get all the added files since a date by using the -D DATE argument instead:

```
cvs history -a -x A -D DATE
```

There is a bunch of other options too, look around in the full documentation if you need any more: [history command documentation](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_16.html#SEC144)

Comment: I am getting a lot of warnings like
cvs server: warning: history line 806 invalid

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Looks like you have a corrupt history file.  You can fix the file by doing something like what this guy did: http://www.mail-archive.com/info-cvs@gnu.org/msg21486.html .  Besides history there are some other ways of finding out new files.  if you use cvs -n update on a directory it'll print the output like normal but won't actually do any updating, you could then compare the files printed and the files actually in the directory.  If it's a large directory you could write a little script to do it.